SearchKit Returns No Contacts for Group that Has Contacts
I am able to use SearchKit to search for contacts in various groups and smart groups, but one specific smart group has no contacts according to SearchKit, even though it definitely has contacts when I navigate to it. I've tried all statuses and so on. Just this one specific group as far as I know. What can it be about the group that makes its contacts invisible to SearchKit?

When you search for "Group Contacts" in SearchKit, it only works on non-smart groups.
To search for contacts within a smart group, start with "Contact" (or "Individual") as the base entity of your search, and then add "In Groups" to the where clause.

Thank you; that makes sense, except that I was sure that SOME smart groups did  show up in SearchKit. Yes, some smart groups are found by SearchKit.
